# Why method call is giving error?

Tags: java, int, overloading, short

When I am writing this code I am getting error

```
public class MethodOverloading 
{

void m(short i)
{
System.out.println("SHort");
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

MethodOverloading ml=new MethodOverloading();
ml.m(10);
}

}
```

I am getting error that m(short) is not applicable for m(int) but when I am 
assigning int value to short then no error then if am not able to pass int 
value as an argument to method that accepts short then how short variable is accepting int value as below?

```
short d=10;
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 3):

Narrowing conversion can occur in an assignment unlike literals being passed to a method. From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the `int` to `short`, because 10 is considered like an int not a short :

```
ml.m((short)10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m1.m((short) 10);
```

Cast the 10 (since there's no type associated with it Java assumes it's a 32-bit int instead of a 16-bit short) to a short.

Answer (score 0):

This is static binding, and the assignment operator '=' is not strict on down casting.But method binder is strict on type. Just  imagine you have one more method void m(int i)  along with void m(int i) the method binder must bind the call to the right method. So it must be strict.

In short s = 10 case, jdk will downcast the value on compilation, so the value will be assigned to s will be down caste of short 10, also if you try to assign a real int range value say 99999999 it will not compile.

Finally static method binding is strict on type.